# How to execute script that opens interactive and continues inside container

Tags: bash, docker, interactive

Hello i want to create a script that starts an `interactive session` with a docker container , and then reads a file from that container's filesystem (and maybe more).

How can i can make the commands from a `bash` script execute inside that session ?

**myscript.sh**

```
docker exec -it server0 bash
cat dock.txt  --this  file is in the container filesystem and i want to see it
//do more stuff in the filesystem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1

You can add multiple actions in:

```
docker exec server0 /bin/sh -c "cmd1;cmd2;...;cmdn"
```

Option 2

You add your script from local folder with volume (-v) parameter and then execute it inside docker:

```
docker exec -it -v ./myscript.sh:/myscript.sh server0 /myscript.sh
```

**myscript.sh**

```
cat dock.txt  
ls -la
//do more stuff in the filesystem
//do more stuff in the filesystem
```

**start.sh**

```
docker exec -it -v ./myscript.sh:/myscript.sh server0 /myscript.sh
```

Start script locally:

```
./start.sh
```